# Why do some Breslov chasiddim have the custom to wear white yamalkas?

Tags: color, kippa-yarmulka, breslov

Many Jews tend to wear black yamalkas and that seems to be the widespread custom among [Yeshivish, Modern Orthodox, Chasidic and Haredi Jews](//en.wikipedia.org/?oldid=644422587#Types_and_variation).

It seems that Breslover Chassidim have the custom to wear white yamalkas with a different style and knitting:

[image: white, knit yamalka that is shaped to fit over the entire head]

What is the reason for this custom?

Comment: http://www.breslevcity.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%91_4219

Comment: @GershonGold, you could translate that link as an answer. :) Google translate doesn't always do a good job (http://dpaste.com/3PMJ8BG#wrap).

Comment: It only explains why it is done on Shabbos. I do not think it answers your question completely.

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say that wearing a black kippah is "the widespread custom" among Modern Orthodox. In Israel, the Modern-Orthodox subset of the dati leumi tend not to wear black kippas, because a black kippah is associated with charedim. In the US, black kippas are pretty common among the Modern Orthodox, but other colors are also very common.

Comment: That's a Yerushalmi kippah with "Na Nach" modifications

Comment: @Kordovero, even in America, not everyone wears a BVY or the like. Many of my friends wear colourful kippot serugot, including a scion of the Teitz rabbinic family.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt So such kippas are/the norm among Yerushalmi Jews? Have you seen old photos of traditional Yerushalmi Jews wearing them? Just wondering!

Comment: @Kordovero, No, but I've seen other fromm Yerushalmim wearing them (in particular, the Shomrei Emunim and their associated sects)

Comment: Real breslov chassidim wear the poileshe livush. These guys who wear the big yarmulkes and scream na nach etc etc don't represent actual Breslov chassidus

Comment: this isn't the normal Breslov minhag. Those who run around chanting na nach and have the oversized white kipas have created some silly mockery of Breslov.

Answer (score 4):

Probably because, according to Breslov tradition, Rebbe Nachman's own kippah was of a similar style and color. Here is a photograph reputed to be of Rebbe Nachman's kippah:

http://www.breslov.com/Gallery/pic232.jpg

Note that many Breslovers wear a white kippah of that style, but without the "Na Nach" slogan. (The vast majority of Breslovers are not adherents of the "Na Nach" sub-group within Breslov.) Others, probably the majority of Breslov chassidim, wear black kippas.

Comment: Ha http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1304/yoel I always thought it was some sort of building/monument.